# No tiller when installing Helm with terraform in a K8S cluster on DigitalOcean

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, digital-ocean, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy a new cluster on DigitalOcean using Terraform, the main idea is to deploy Fission to have a serverless environment, here are my files:

**do_provider.tf**

```
provider "digitalocean" {
  token = "${var.do_token}"
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable region {
  description = "Region for cloud resources."
  default     = "lon1"
}
```

**k8s_cluster.tf**

```
resource "random_id" "fission-cluster" {
  byte_length = 8
}

resource "digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster" "fission-cluster" {
  name = "k8s-fission-${var.region}-${random_id.fission-cluster.hex}"
  region = "${var.region}"
  version =  "1.15.3-do.3"
  node_pool {
    name = "k8s-fission-${var.region}-${random_id.fission-cluster.hex}-worker"
    size = "s-1vcpu-2gb"
    node_count = "3"
    tags = ["fission", "worker"]
  }
  tags = ["fission"]
}

resource "local_file" "config" {
    content     = "${digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster.kube_config.0.raw_config}"
    filename = "${path.module}/config"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = "${digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster.endpoint}"

  client_certificate     = "${base64decode(digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster.kube_config.0.client_certificate)}"
  client_key             = "${base64decode(digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster.kube_config.0.client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}
```

**helm.tf**

```
provider "helm" {
    service_account = "tiller"
    install_tiller = true
    namespace = "kube-system"
    kubernetes {
      config_path =  "${path.module}/config"
      load_config_file = true
    }
}

data "helm_repository" "stable" {
  name = "stable"
  url  = "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com"
}

resource "kubernetes_service_account" "tiller" {
  metadata {
    name      = "tiller"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
  depends_on =  [ "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding.tiller" ]
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "tiller" {
  metadata {
    name = "tiller"
  }
  role_ref {
      api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
      kind = "ClusterRole"
      name = "cluster-admin"
  }
  subject {
      kind = "User"
      name = "admin"
      api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
  subject {
      kind = "ServiceAccount"
      name = "tiller"
      namespace = "kube-system"
  }
  subject {
      kind = "Group"
      name = "system:masters"
      api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
}
```

When I run `terrarform plan` it show the changes correctlly and also when I run `terraform apply` cluster is created and shows the output as correct

```
random_id.fission-cluster: Creating...
random_id.fission-cluster: Creation complete after 0s [id=dag8ooN_yVg]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Creating...
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [1m20s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [1m30s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [1m40s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [1m50s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [2m0s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [2m10s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [2m20s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [2m30s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [2m40s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [2m50s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [3m0s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [3m10s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [3m20s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [3m30s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [3m40s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [3m50s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [4m0s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [4m10s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [4m20s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [4m30s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [4m40s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [4m50s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [5m0s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [5m10s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [5m20s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [5m30s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [5m40s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Still creating... [5m50s elapsed]
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.fission-cluster: Creation complete after 5m52s [id=a2dbf847-a273-41c0-a5f7-5aab8ab21407]
local_file.config: Creating...
local_file.config: Creation complete after 0s [id=bab7483e4abd5e02e473464556055c80ec952826]
kubernetes_service_account.tiller: Creating...
kubernetes_service_account.tiller: Creation complete after 2s [id=kube-system/tiller]

Apply complete! Resources: 4 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

The problem is that after all the process the tiller is not deployed inside the cluster and the helm cli command request to initialize the tiller first.

**UPDATE**

The helm.tf file was wrong

Comment: did you manage to get it working ?

Comment: Yes, with the terraform files I posted and the help of seeing the correct log level indicated on the first answer, the problem was that I was not defining any `helm_release`, you have to define a `helm_release` to force the tiller to be installed

Comment: ok,yes, same for me. that's what I eventually realized later on hehe

Answer (score 2):

The tiller component should be installed by default with the helm terraform provider. However it looks for the kube config file by default at path:

```
~/.kube/config
```

In your configuration, it looks like you're saving the new Kubernetes cluster kube config into the module path with your local_file config resource.

i.e.

```
"${path.module}/config"
```

So I would adjust your kubernetes block in the helm provider section to add something like:

```
load_config_file = "${path.module}/config"
```

Failing that, enable a higher log debug level when running - perhaps the failure to initialize the helm tiller component is a silent warning or info log message.

Try set the **TF_LOG** environment variable to **TRACE**. [Debugging docs for Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html)

Comment: The `TF_LOG` set to `TRACE` shows me this `[DEBUG] pruning unused provider.helm`, why is ignoring the provider?